# Автодополнение кода в шаблонах django в PyCharm Community

Tags: python, python-3.x, html5, pycharm

Не могу найти комбинацию горячих клавиш для автодополнения кода при работе в PyCharm c html5 файлом.

**1.**
После ввода кода:

```
{%
```

и нажатия горячих клавиш стало так:

```
{%   %}
```

**2.**
После ввода кода:

```
{}
```

и нажатия грячих клавиш стало так:

```
{% block sidebar %}{% endblock %}
```

---

Все это увидел в видеокурсе по работе с Django [тут](https://youtu.be/vU7u5c2XNQU?list=PLrgHtaQ10vi3xalWI7q6Uzr7aZUNT0BJH&t=185) и [тут](https://youtu.be/oglp0B0K470?list=PLrgHtaQ10vi3xalWI7q6Uzr7aZUNT0BJH&t=485) (ссылки именно на эти моменты видеокурса, нашел на yotube.com). Объяснений того, какие автор использует горячие клавиши не было, а найденные в интернете горячие клавиши не работают как в примере (наверно в PyCharm можно сохранять свои варианты автодополнения кода, но как это делать не знаю)

Comment: Если у вас PyCharm Community, то не будут работать многие фишки, которые есть в Professional версии, в том числе и расширенная поддержка html шаблонов.

Comment: Нашел этот курс на ютубе, ссылку на видео добавил в вопрос сверху (у автора простая PyCharm Community версия)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Похоже это сделано через Live Templates ("Живые шаблоны"). Пример настройки для шаблона block/endblock:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Работает так: в html файле вы вводите `{}` (то что указано в поле "Abbrevation"), жмете <kbd>Tab</kbd> (или кнопку выбранную в комбо "Expand with", если там что-то другое - можно например поставить чтобы дополнялось при нажатии пробела), фигурные скобки заменяются на текст `{% block  %}{% endblock %}`, курсор становится туда, где стоит `$SELECTION$` в тексте шаблона.

Вообще, мне кажется, удобнее было бы сделать шаблон для `for` (так как он довольно часто используется). Например, аббревиатура `{for` или просто `for`, шаблон `{% for $SELECTION$ %}{% endfor %}`.

Чтобы работало, обязательно должен быть выбран контекст - HTML под полем текста шаблона (там где на скриншоте `Applicable in HTML: HTML Text; HTML`). При создании шаблона там будет "No applicable contexts." - нужно нажать на Define и выбрать HTML.

Для двойной скобки более простой шаблон: `{{ $SELECTION$ }}`

Answer (score 1):

В настройках можно включить автодополнение, но оно попроще будет чем в видео.

1. Заходим в настройки;
2. Находим пункт `Languages & Frameworks`;
3. Находим пункт `Template Languages`;
4. Для `HTML` выбираем `Django` в выпадающем списке.

UPD: как ниже отметили, работает только для PyCharm Professional

[image]

Comment: Это не работает в PyCharm Community, только в Professional

Comment: текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст ответа можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста ответа